# Is there a way to code a for loop so that it doesn't increment through a sequence?

Tags: c#

I have this loop:

```
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

But instead I would like to have i for just numbers 1,2,4,5 and 7 and  I will hardcode this.

Is there a way I can do this with something like an array?

Comment: create an array of your required numbers & use foreach

Comment: Could give more details so we can help provide relevant solutions? How often do you plan on skipping numbers? How many numbers do you expect to skip? How do you know which numbers to skip? Why are you skipping numbers in the first place? What and how are you hardcoding this?

Comment: it's not that easy as I thought in the beginning to find a duplicate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use an array to give the numbers you want like this

```
int[] loop = new int[] {1,2,4,5,7};
foreach(int i in loop)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Or do it inline which is not as clean when the list of values grows in my opinion

```
foreach(int i in new int[] {1,2,4,5,7})
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: The second one is cleaner to me - the array is only in scope during the loop. Also, to make it really "clean", you can remove the `int` declaration, since the compiler will determine that from the contents.

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach (int i in new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 })
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically the answers here are correct, just because you asked explicitly for a `for` instead of a `foreach` loop:

```
int[] loop = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 };
for (int i = 0; i< loop.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(loop[i]);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/c5yjPe

Answer (score 0):

If you want particularly for loop then go with this :

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 };
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the right answer for the *general case* is to use `foreach` or an indexed lookup as shown in the other answers, but just for completeness' sake:

You can use **any** statement within a `for` expression, including conditionals. With that in mind, it is easy to build a conditional increment or even an *exhaustive* conditional (state machine?) for a required set:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i += (i == 5 || i == 2) ? 2 : 1)
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
// Output: 12457

for (int i = 1; i > 0; i = i switch {1=>2, 2=>4, 4=>5, 5=>7, 7=>-1})
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
// Output: 12457
```

Or even something really silly like a self indexing lookup:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i > 0; i = new []{0,2,4,0,5,7,0,-1}[i])
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
// Output: 12457
```